# Bouncing Robots: Graphical Puzzle

Tags: open-ended, optimization, pencil-and-paper-games

[image: Robot Puzzle]

Robots are indicated by the arrowhead shapes and the labels "r", "y", "b", "g". The label obviously corresponds to their color. The aim of the puzzle is to pick up the shapes and put them down in the grey circle located on the north side of the board.

### Rules

- Robots can only move in a straight line. Along the light blue paths they start on.
- Robots keep moving until they hit either a Wall or another Robot.
- Robots can only pick up a shape that is of their own color (red Robot can only pick up red shapes).
- Robots will automatically pickup a shape when they land on it.
- Robots can only carry up to 7 sides, going over this limit destroys the Robot, rendering it unavailable for use. Example: Red Robot has picked up a Red Hexagon and a Red Circle. This gives him 7 sides (6 + 1). If Red Robot picked up a Red Triangle, he would be destroyed. To avoid this you need to put shapes down in the grey circle.
- Robots can only move one at a time.

The aim of the game is to places all of the shapes into the grey circle which is a puzzle in itself. I posted it here because I want to see how well people can optimize their paths.

Post your solutions in the format "r s" for Red Robot move South.

**Just to clarify** One Move ("r s") = One Turn.

Comment: Robots can only move in a straight line? Also, they "keep moving until they hit either another wall or robot" and then what? they stop? they change direction? which direction?

Comment: Circles don't have vertices...

Comment: What kind of shape has only one corner, then? ... A teardrop?

Comment: @Aify Thanks for that, I've made edits to clarify. 

keep moving until they hit either another wall or robot" and then what? they stop?  **Yes, they stop** then you move them in another direction (North, South, East, West)

Comment: So at the grey circle the rule that says that robots block other robots is not applicable?

Comment: Do the robots move in parallel or concurrently? e.g. If green moves towards red and vice versa on a straight line without obstacles, will they hit each other in the middle of their path? Or is it that only one robot moves at a time?

Comment: @Ivo Beckens The rule still applies

Comment: @CygnusX1 the robots move one at a time

Comment: Hmm, this is quite the challenge.

Comment: I did this in 191 Turns, to clarify. One move = one turn

Comment: "Along the light blue paths they start on." Do you mean grey? (The average colour of the paths is #D2D2D2.)

Comment: @IanMacDonald It looks blue on my screen. They travel along the paths they are on. I feel like it is clear although I'll make clarification if you have any to suggest :)

Comment: @PuzzleEater , What happens if red robot hits a blue shape? When robot hits grey circle, does it remain on board or is removed from the board?

Comment: Shapes don't block movement. Only Walls and other Robots do. When a Robot lands on a Shape, if the Shape and Robot are the same colour then the Shape is automatically picked up. If not then the Shape is not picked up. 
When a Robot carrying a Shape lands on the Grey Circle, the Shape is automatically placed down on the Grey Circle and can no longer be picked up no matter what.

Comment: Could I suggest labeling your grid? Perhaps letter across the top / bottom and numbers down the sides like a chess board? That might make discussions easier.

Comment: FYI: So far as I can tell, the only way to land on the gray circle is to use another robot to force you to stop along certain walls.

Comment: Do the robots move in turn, alternately (i.e. red first, then yellow, then blue, then green, and back to red), or is it allowed that one color can move a certain number of times before the next color (e.g., red moves south 6 times, then green moves south once, east once, and north 6 times)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution of 137 moves utilizing the idea of getting a robot to the eighth column of the first row to create paths to the grey circle. Although this is unlikely to be optimal, it is a major improvement on PuzzleEater's 191 moves. The format is "[robot] [sequence of moves]".

```
r esen                         + r circle
y en
r e
y s
r sesw nwsw                    + r hexagon, - circle hexagon, + square
g wnws e                       + g circle
b sene nwn                     + b hexagon
g wnws wnwn ene                + g hexagon
r news enen eswn               + r triangle, - square triangle (finished)
b ws                           + b circle
y n                            
g nwnw enes enw                - g circle hexagon, + triangle square
y s
r w
g eswn                         - g triangle square (finished)
y wnws esen s                  + y circle triangle
r e
g e
b nwsn esws eses wsen e        - b hexagon circle, + b square triangle
g wses
b swne sws                     - b square triangle (finished)
y nwse nesw nesn wsne swne s   - y circle triangle, + square, - square, + hexagon
r e
b ne
y nes                          - y hexagon (finished)
```